# Can anyone tell me how to find permittivity of a dielectric sample using a rectangular waveguide

Tags: simulation, waveguide

Im trying to find the material paramters of a dielectric sample using a waveguide(X band) employing the Transmission/Reflection technique. While performing simulation in CST, how to properly orient the sample inside? Is it necessary that the waveguide is flared?

Answer (score -1):

See if this works:

[A New Method to Determine the Complex Permittivity and Complex Permeability of Dielectric Materials at X-Band Frequencies](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/57bb/47e818dfe3e8c5597c5dfa9b701b09b1772a.pdf), Hassan Elmajid, Jaouad Terhzaz,Hassan Ammor, Mohamed Chaïbi, Angel Mediavilla, INTERNATIONAL JOURNAL OF MICROWAVE AND OPTICAL TECHNOLOGY, VOL.10, NO.1, JANUARY 2015

Comment: That is rather short for an answer.  Could you include some details of the paper, and how the technique presented there applies to simulations using the [CST Simulia EM field](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/products/cst-studio-suite/) software?

Comment: Sir, I was also referring to the same paper. With reference to the paper how  exactly should I simulate in CST. Is it necessary to use a coax to waveguide transition , or can I directly feed the rectangular waveguide using the waveguide port in CST